# Transaction Scope Locks table

Tags: c#, sql, transactionscope

I am using C# 3.5 and I have a code within transaction scope that is locking the tables , how can I prevent the transaction scope from locking these tables ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use keywords to prevent table locking, such as nolock, but pay attention how you read them, for example read committed or read uncommited, as this may leave you with the so called, dirty reads.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `TransactionScope` with the option `RequireNew` and set the `IsolationLevel` to `ReadUncommitted`:

```
using (var t = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequireNew,
new TransactionOptions { 
    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted 
}))
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am trying it , but is there any drawbacks of it ?

Comment: Yes: You're not participating in the transaction. You asked for that, but you should know what you're doing. There is a reason for the encapsulating transaction, isn't it?

Comment: ah !you mean there will be no rollback or commit ?

Comment: Yes. The code will be executed as if it was outside of the enclosing transaction and thereby will prevent locking tables. Be aware that if the tables have been locked already, this solution won't help.

Comment: not this the required ! cannot I enclose the code in transaction but without locking tables? like nolock in Sql?

Comment: I modified the answer to create a new transaction using ReadUncommitted. This should allow reading locked data.

Comment: This will allow the code inside the transaction block to read uncommitted data,right? but what about the code outside this block?in any other window form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67448/discussion-between-frank-and-hasan-shouman).

Answer (score 2):

The `TransactionScope` makes the code block transactional. The inwolved tables are locked while "code" has not been `COMMITED/ROLLED BACK`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding

`with(nolock)`

to the SQL stored procedures that are involved in the transaction.